# Neural network: finding irrelevant inputs

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-networks, pruning

I am training a neural network and I suspect that some of the inputs might be irrelevant -- they might not have any relationship to the output. How do I identify these inputs so I can get rid of them? (I am assuming that I should get rid of irrelevant inputs, right?)

Example:

```
set.seed(123)
nr = 1000
nc = 25
xx = as.data.frame(matrix(runif(nr * nc, min=-1, max=1), nrow = nr, ncol = nc))
# y is only a function of V1 - V5
xx = within(xx, y <- V1^2 + V2*V3 + V4^3 + log(V5 + 2))
# But we train using V1 - V25
nn = nnet(y ~ ., size = 5, linout = TRUE, data=xx, MaxNWts = 10e3, maxit=10e3)
```

Now what? `nn$wts` has all the weights, and `summary(nn)` presents the same weights in a more human-readable format. Can these be used for anything? Ideally, a function / package for doing this has already been written -- I just have not been able to find it.

Answer (score 2):

I am suggesting a general solution for any model that you can also use to neural networks as well. Unfortunately, I am not a R user. So, I cannot ensure that the R functions for R below really work.

You may select features considering the importance of the features for out of sample prediction. In this context, I suggest two very interesting and general methods that you can use:

1) [Permutation importance](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/permutation_importance.html): The permutation feature importance is defined to be the decrease in a model score when a single feature value is randomly shuffled

**Solution in R**: [Permutation importance in R](https://rdrr.io/cran/mmpf/man/permutationImportance.html)

2) [Shap values](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/11/shapley-value-machine-learning-interpretability-game-theory/): It is not an easy concept since it is based in game theory, but it shows the importance of each feature.

**Solution in R**: [Shap values in R](https://www.r-bloggers.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-shap-values-in-r/)